# "Hadamard's Maximum Determinant Problem" What is the maximum determinant value of 3x3 matrix whose entries consist of only 3 and 0.

Tags: determinant

I'm currently studying linear algebra. I faced one question that bothers me so hard.

The question is about Hadamard's Maximum Determinant Problem.

Since I cannot understand the concept of this, I need understandable explanation with

following question.

- What is the maximum determinant value of 3x3 matrix whose entries
  consist of only 3 and 0.

I will keep watching on this post, so I wanna communicate with you about this question.

Thanks !

Comment: http://oeis.org/A003432 gives the maximum determinant for matrices with entries of $0,1$.  How does your determinant relate?

Comment: $\pmatrix{3&3&0\cr0&3&3\cr3&0&3\cr}$

Comment: @GerryMyerson How did you get the answer?

Comment: A little educated trial-and-error goes a long way.

Answer (score 0):

I used

$$\begin{pmatrix}
3&0&3\\
3&3&0\\
0&3&3\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

for a determinant of $3(9) + 0 + 3(9) = 54$. I wanted to maximize the determinants of minors with a positive sign, and for the negative one I chose to make the determinant 0.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, I want to solve this question by using Hadamard's method. (I tried to find the maximum value by using the same method that you used, and it works.) Can you tell me how to solve this question by using Hadamard's method? Thanks again :)

Comment: @JasonYu Ah, I didn't realize there was a such a method.